# Which Open source CEP shoud I choose for distributed and pipelined processing ; siddhi, Flink , Esper?

Tags: apache-flink, complex-event-processing, esper, siddhi

I am little bised towards siddhi cep as it has siddhi query language but it uses storm for distributed processing and WSO2 provides an web interface / dashboard to create and deploy applications . I think it will give me less independence to enhance / use some features .

Flink on the other hand seems to be good choice but it requires lot of code to implement even simple logic.

Is there a better option than these , I am
Confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a test...create 10 queries in each system....something like....

```
  select * from SomeEvent where value = 1
  select * from SomeEvent where value = 2
  ...
  select * from SomeEvent where value = 9
  select * from SomeEvent where value = 10
```

The idea is to see how easy it is to create the queries, how the API or deploy steps work and how performance changes with the number of queries.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by less independence? You can use Siddhi 4.x [1] without depending on storm by using its source and sink features to receive and send messages from one instance to another using tcp, Kafka, http, etc. 
WSO2 Stream processor also uses the new version of Siddhi and with its editor you and simulate events and also debug.

Update: From 4.1 [WSO2 Stream Processor][2] can run on top of Kafka in fully distributed mode. See https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP4xx/Fully+Distributed+Deployment.

[1] https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/

[2] https://wso2.com/analytics